# reload table in WatchKit

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

We have a hierarchical watch app.

The root controller is a table of menu items.  That list of items is controlled by a server.  The data is retrieved and stored in core data. The menu is populated the first time going into the app.

But I want this table to stay current. My thought was to add code to `willActivate` to check if there was changes, and reload the table.  In my reload logic I call the same function I called the first time, which sets the `menuTable.setNumberOfRows` and creates each row.  Looking at what I'm putting in the logs, it is going through this logic with a different count of rows and new labels.  But the app on the watch shows the table with the old data.

How can I get this table to reload with the new information?

Comment: Did you log your new items?

Comment: I logged the new count I was assigning, and the new labels in each row.  But the table doesn't change.

Comment: Check this post: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1098875#1098875

Comment: I saw that, but they were talking about beta releases at first.  And it didn't seem to have an answer.  I tried setting it to an empty string first and that did not make a difference for me.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem too and as rmp says, it still seems to be a bug in watchOS 1.0.1. The problem appears when you try to reload your tableView after run `willActivate()` and nothing will happen.

In my case, I reload the tableView after receive a reply from a delegate and then I reload all the content just if it's necessary. To achieve this, I remove all rows from a NSIndexSet and load again.

```
if isNecessary {
    self.table.removeRowsAtIndexes(NSIndexSet(indexesInRange: NSMakeRange(0, maxItems)))
    isNecessary = false
}
```

I've tried a lot of tricks but none has worked for me:

- Force to reload rows by `table.setNumberOfRows(0, withRowType: "data")`
- Setting parameters to empty text before assign new values

One thing you could do is to hide tableView before removing rows, and avoid the remove animation.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in WatchKit. Seems like Apple doesn't handle the repetitive interface object correctly.

The general principle here is: Only insert or remove necessary rows after a table is created. Do **not** reload the whole table like what we usually do in iOS. It just doesn't work (or trigger the bug).

So specifically, you have to:

- Do this in `willActivated` method. This is correct.
- If this is the first load, before the table is even created, do what you are now doing – load all table rows.
- For all following times, don't reload the table, fetch the new data and check the desired number of rows.
- Compare with the current number of rows in the table, insert to or remove from the bottom of the existing table.
- Now simply re-assign the new data to all existing rows. Again, do not reload.

It should work if you follow the above steps.

Comment: How do you find the the correct row from the table and update its content? For example, the first row might not equal the first object in the new array anymore, after the data has been refreshed. Do you have to loop through each row and each object in the array and compare the id for example, if they match, replace the content, if non is found, add it. Then, you have to find the ones that don't exist anymore and remove them from the table.. sounds bad..

Comment: @VanDuTran: well actually you don't have to. You just need to re-assign all data to all rows after you adjusted the number of rows. Based on my experiment, the WatchKit bug is that their proxy objects can't property handle new and destructed row objects in the same run loop. As long as you are only append new rows or delete rows from the bottom, you are fine.

Comment: @VanDuTran If this solves your problem, please accept it as an answer; otherwise please let me know what else I can do to address it.

Comment: @RicharBao this is not my question, i can't accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found what works best given the current state of watchkit is to remove all rows then re-populate the table.

Try something like this:

```
- (void)loadTableData{

    //clear the table
    [mainTableView setNumberOfRows:0 withRowType:@"myTableRow"];

    //set the row count again
    [mainTableView setNumberOfRows:numberOfRows withRowType:@"myTableRow"];

    //populate table

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple. As Apple hasn't provided any method to reload the data.
You can still achieve that by simply populating the rows for the tableview.

Below is the sample code:

```
        for index in 0..<tracksTableView.numberOfRows {
        if let controller = tracksTableView.rowController(at: index) as? EditPlaylistRowController {
            controller.playingTrackId = self.playingTrackID
            controller.sharedTrack = trackItems[index]
        }
    }
```

Use it whenever you want to refresh the data.

> NOTE:
>   You can still make some conditional statements inside the row controller class.

Happy to help :)